# Pass class variable into method of another class in java

Tags: java, class, variables, methods

Im just start learning java renow .i created a class student which contain variable ID and name and another class studentlist that is an arraylist of student.

I want to create seach function that allow to pass variale's name of stunt class (ID or name) and the variable value. how can i do it ?

```
class Student{
    String ID;
    String name;

    public Student(){

    }

    public Student(String ID,String name){
        this.ID =  ID;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getStudent() {
        String info = this.ID +"\t\t\t"+ this.name;
        return info;
   }
}


class StudentList{

    private ArrayList <Student> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private int counter = 0;
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public StudentList(){
    
    }

    public StudentList(Student stu){
        Student student = new Student(stu.ID,stu.name);
        this.list.add(student);
        this.counter++;
    }
    public int seach(String type(name or ID) , String value ){
        int i;
        int found = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < list.size();i++){

            if(value.equals(list.get(i).type){
                found++;
                System.out.println(value.equals(list.get(i).type);
            }
        }

        return found;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create getter for ID and name in Class Student.
Than you can ask in seach

```
    public int seach(String type , String value ){
    int i;
    int found = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < list.size();i++){
        Student student =  list.get(i);
        if(value.equals(student.getID()) || value.equals(student.getName())){
            found++;
            System.out.println(value.equals(list.get(i).type);
        }
    }

    return found;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First I recommend to set the attributes of your `Student` class to private. Then you could add setters and getters.

```
public class Student {
   private String ID;
   private String name;

   public Student() {}

   public Student(String ID, String name) {
     this.ID = ID;
     this.name = name;
   }

   public String getID() { return ID; }
   public String getName() { return name;
   public void setID(String ID) { this.ID = ID; }
   public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

In your class `StudentList` I would split and extend the functionalities of the search instead of passing the value type as an additional argument.

```
public class StudentList {
      ...
      public int searchByName(String name) {
         for(int i=0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if(list.get(i).getName().equals(name)) return i;
         }
         
         return -1;
      }

      public int searchByID(String ID) {    
         for(int i=0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if(list.get(i).getID().equals(ID)) return i;
         }
         
         return -1;
      }

      public int searchStudent(Student stud) { return list.indexOf(stud); }
}
```

If you really need a function that bundles all of that you could add another function that decides by a flag which function should be called with the passed argument. You could also add a check for arguments here while having more flexibility and separation of responsibilities.

```
public int search(int flag, arg Object) {
    if(flag == 0) return searchStudent((Student) arg);
    else if(flag == 1) return searchByID((String) arg);
    else return searchByName((String) arg);
}
```

Additional side note: if you want to indicate the current number of students in the list with your `counter` variable, I highly recommend to remove this variable and always call the `size()` method of your list when needed. Every Java collection (i.e. ArrayList) provides it and it will always return the correct value after removing or adding students. Implementing your own counter for this task will result in a more error prone source code.